# Tool/setup to create an app/web app that runs python scripts with custom options

Tags: python, c#, angular

I am trying to make a web app or a standalone app that runs on windows and macos through which I can control some aspects of the python scripts I have visually. It will be a control panel on deciding which data gets saved, which gets deleted and the way in which the scripts run.

Is there a quick way of achieving this and then be able to run locally on any pc/mac from the form of an executable/web app without having a remote server?

Design doesn't matter, time is most important, I should be able to do this quickly, web would mean the quickest, but if it's something that has a designer tool that's okay too.

Comment: By 'visual', do you mean only mouse clicks allowed? I'm asking because a very quick way could be to create a CLI using Python's argparse library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). Or, I haven't tried using Google's python-fire library yet, which is suppose to automate the CLI creation (https://github.com/google/python-fire)